# Placeholder internet explorer 11 not showing

Tags: html, internet-explorer, placeholder

I have a problem with placeholders in IE 11 even though it says in compatibility table that IE 11 can show placeholders. I am not talking about focus on input. There are no placeholders also when I am not focused on input box.

IE Version: 11.0.9600

I have no css applied on the placeholders.

In other browsers placeholder is showing.

I tried also compatibility using meta tags, no change.

```
<input id="textinput" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-md" /></input>
```

Comment: Input tags are self-closing. There is no `</input>`. You might want to run your page through a HTML validator to see if there are other errors.

Comment: no luck here, I fixed errors from validator, tried disabling all stylesheets so only pure html remained, but nothing shows up.

Comment: try a minimalist markup <input type="text" name="txtinput" id="txtinput" placeholder="whatever"/> (Note: by convention id and name should use the same string. Certain strings like "name" my conflict with global variables or attribute names). Use the DOM Explorer tab of the dev tool to examine the style rules applied to an element, specifically any -webkit-appearance or color or :placeholder rules. Post a reproducable mashup to a jsfiddle for better assistance.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks but without luck :( fricking internet explorer...

Answer (score 2):

Okay folks, I just discovered that my lovely company has installed IE 11 but with forced IE 8 view - my god.

- Nevertheless, I solved the problem with this jQuery script, now it is working.
  https://codepen.io/engza/pen/DptoH

whole code in the link

`$(function(){$("input, textarea").placeholder()`

Comment: use the Emulation tab of IE's dev tools to find out which IE Emulation mode (aka documentMode) your dev/test/production site is using and how it was established. eg. IE8/Enterprise Site Mode lists. When developing on a localhost, use the File>Properties menu to determine which IE security zone it is mapped to... expected Internet.

Comment: Hi Rob, yes this is the way I discovered this, anyway thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this on another Stackoverflow question but maybe I can help people in this question too.

I had the same problem and found out that it was the setting of my CSS framework (Foundation) that put a height of 2.4375rem to all inputs... You need to override that! With something like

```
[type=color],
[type=date],
[type=datetime-local],
[type=datetime],
[type=email],
[type=month],
[type=number],
[type=password],
[type=search],
[type=tel],
[type=text],
[type=time],
[type=url],
[type=week],
textarea {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 will not display the placeholder if you focus on the input using JavaScript or normal User Interaction.

Answer (score 0):

add below *placeholder-label.js* as an external js.

```
( function( $ ) {
  var IE10 = !!(navigator && navigator.userAgent && navigator.userAgent.match('MSIE 10'));
  var IE11 = !!(navigator && navigator.userAgent && navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./));
  var overridePlaceholder = (IE10 || IE11);

$.fn.placeholder_labels = function(options) {
    var that = this;
    var defaults = {
      blurColor  : '#aaaaaa',
      focusColor : '#bbbbbb',
      labelClass : 'placeholder-label'
    }

var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

// test if HTML5 placeholder is supported or we do not want to
// override default placeholder behavior; if so, quit
if ('placeholder' in document.createElement('input') && !overridePlaceholder) {
  return this;
}

// Go through each input and/or text area and add a placeholder label
// should be envoked as follows
// $("input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]").placeholder_labels();
this.each(function(){
  var $input = $( this );
  var placeholder_text = $input.attr( 'placeholder' );

  if (overridePlaceholder) $input.attr('placeholder', '');

  var line_height = {};
  if( !$input.is('textarea') && $input.css('height') != 'auto') {
    line_height = { lineHeight: '23px', whiteSpace: 'nowrap' };
    //add line height as below if having alignment
    //$input.css('height')
  }

  // create a label and a span within it
  var $label = $( '<label></label>' ).addClass(settings.labelClass);
  $label.css("width", "100%");
  var $span = $( '<span>' + placeholder_text + '</span>' );
  $span.appendTo( $label );

  // Copy input styles and apply them to the placeholder
  // should get it 95% of the way toward looking right
  $span.css($.extend({
    position:'absolute',
    display: 'inline',
    float: 'none',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: settings.blurColor,
    cursor: 'text',
    paddingTop: $input.css('padding-top'),
    paddingRight: $input.css('padding-right'),
    paddingBottom: $input.css('padding-bottom'),
    paddingLeft: $input.css('padding-left'),
    marginTop: $input.css('margin-top'),
    marginRight: $input.css('margin-right'),
    marginBottom: $input.css('margin-bottom'),
    marginLeft: $input.css('margin-left'),
    fontSize: $input.css('font-size'),
    fontFamily: $input.css('font-family'),
    fontStyle: $input.css('font-style'),
    fontWeight: $input.css('font-weight'),
    textTransform: $input.css('text-transform'),
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    zIndex: 99
  }, line_height));

  $('#typefi-btn-clear-filter').insertAfter('#typefi-files-search-input');
  // the label surrounds the input
  $label.insertBefore( $input ).append( $input );

  // try getting the input's size even if it is hidden
  var w = $input.width(),
      h = $input.height();

  // test for the case of the input being hidden
  if ( !w || !h ) {
    // get dimensions by cloning the input and grabbing height and width
    var $clone = $input.clone().appendTo( 'body' ).css({
      position : 'absolute',
      visibility : 'hidden',
      display : 'block'
    });

    // fetch the correct size (hopefully)
    w = $clone.width();
    h = $clone.height();

    $clone.remove();
  }

  // if the input is hidden or shown, so should the placeholder be
  $input.on('hide', function() {
    $span.hide();
  });
  // when showing, ensure the text is the right size
  $input.on('show', function(){
    $span.show().css({
      width:$input.width()+'px',
      height:$input.height()+'px'
    });
  });

  /* If the input is starting out hidden or there is a default value in
   * the input already, hide the placeholder
   */
  if ( !$input.is(':visible') || $input.val().length ) {
    $span.hide();
  }

  /* Show the placeholder untill a key is pressed in the field
   * restore the placeholder if the field is blank.
   */
  $input
    .on("keydown keyup", function() {
      if ( $(this).val() === "" ) {
        $span.show();
      } else {
        $span.hide();
      }
    })
    .focus( function() {
      $span
        .addClass( "input-selected" )
        .css('color', settings.focusColor);
    })
    .blur( function() {
      $span
        .removeClass( "input-selected" )
        .css('color', settings.blurColor);
    });

  // If the placeholder is focused, send focus to the input
  $span.focus( function() {
    $input.focus();
  });
  
  // If autofocus, refocus input
  if($input.attr("autofocus")){
      $input.focus();
  }
});

// override jQuery.hide() to trigger the 'hide' event
var hide = $.fn.hide;
$.fn.hide = function() {
  this.trigger('hide');
  return hide.apply(this, arguments);
};

// override jQuery.show() to trigger the 'show' event
var show = $.fn.show;
$.fn.show = function() {
  this.trigger('show');
  return show.apply(this, arguments);
};

return that;
  };
})( jQuery );
```

Then Link js in HTML as below.

```
<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js\"></script>
<script src="/js/placeholder-label.js"></script>
<script> 
$( function() {
  $("input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]").placeholder_labels();
});
```