# Why can't IE type in form?

Tags: html, css

My form for the website I'm designing is working fine on Firefox, Edge, and Chrome. But on IE, I can't see the placeholder text and when I try to type, it doesn't show any thing. When I remove the CSS file, then I can see the placeholder text and whatever is typed in the form.

Somethings wrong with the CSS but I'm not sure what:

```
/* Style place holder text and let it show CSS effect upon focus */
.contact-us input[type="text"],
.contact-us input[type="email"],
.contact-us input[type="url"],
.contact-us textarea
{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: grey;
    padding: .7em 0;
}
.contact-us input[type="text"]:focus,
.contact-us input[type="email"]:focus,
.contact-us input[type="url"]:focus,
.contact-us textarea:focus {
  padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: those. are there no placeholder in the inputs on the browser ie? what browser version?

Comment: I downloaded IE just yesterday for testing purposes, its the latest version, IE11. And I'm sorry I didn't get your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582610/placeholder-internet-explorer-11-not-showing) thread after searching some more. Apparently there's something in the CSS framework that sets the height on all inputs to 2.4375rem and it needs to be overridden with something like:

```
.contact-us input[type="text"],
.contact-us input[type="email"],
.contact-us input[type="url"],
.contact-us textarea
{
    height: auto;
}
```